# Omit records based off of case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is for an address list report I have. Basically Clients and programs. A client can be discharged from one program but still active in another, so I want to omit these records for a certain one program.
Right now i'm trying to do something like this in my select:

```
case prg.Program
when 'AES' then c.clientid not in (2938,30495,4958)
else prg.Program
end as test
```

Basically I want these records to not show up when the program is AES. But if they have another program I want them to still come up.  Is this possible?

Also program and clientid are both declared as variables, don't know if that might help

Answer (score 2):

You might want something like this:

```
(case when prg.InterAct_Program <> 'AES' or c.clientid not in (2938, 30495, 4958)
      then prg.InterAct_Program
 end)
```

This will return `NULL` for the value.

You might also want a `where` clause:

```
where (prg.InterAct_Program <> 'AES' or c.clientid not in (2938, 30495, 4958))
```

This will actually filter out the rows.

Comment: The request seems to be to exclude 'AES' records for the listed `clientid` values but not exclude them for non-`AES`, so you'd need `NOT IN (2938, 30495, 4958)`